# How do I find the highest version of a varchar in C#?

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to get the latest version of a program in C#. The code below is the only way I have been able to get the code to run in my controller without any errors:

```
PList = PList.Where(x => x.PSP == LP && x.VERSION == "1.3");
```

The problem is unless I maintain this code through every new version and correct it in the code to the most current version it will not work correctly.

So I thought that I could use a *max* function to get the latest version but it is a varchar in the SQL DB and I cannot change it since I do not have the access to change types.

I have tried different ways of doing this like the example below with no luck.

```
PList = PList.Where(x => x.PSP == LP && x.VERSION.MAX());
```

*Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'char'*

So how can I get the Max version when I need to know if PSP is equal to LP **AND** the version is the highest number in the DB? Thank you for your help!

**Update**

Thank you all for your excellent answers and I can see how some of them might work on their own but none of them have worked with the code I have. I think posting the rest of the code might help make diagnosing the issue a little easier, so here is the rest of the code.

```
public virtual ActionResult getAjaxP(string TP = null)
{
    if (TP != null)
    {
        var PList = from x in db.iamp_mapping select x;
        PList = PList.Where(x => x.PSP == TP);
        return Json(PList.Select(x => new { x.PS }).Distinct().ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take advantage of the [System.Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxyt63s%28v=vs.100%29) class.

```
var maxVersion = PList
    .Select(x => new Version(x.VERSION))
    .Max()
    .ToString();

PList = PList.Where(x => x.PSP == LP && x.VERSION == maxVersion);
```

This will favor "1.11" over "1.3", for instance.

If this is Linq-to-Sql, it might involve an extra call to the database.

Answer (score 4):

It's unfortunate that your version numbers are stored as text. That means that "1.11" is actually earlier than "1.3".

Aside from that, you could use `OrderByDescending`. For example

```
var item = PList.Where(x => x.PSP == LP)
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.VERSION)
                .First();
```

That will get the *single item* with the highest version number. If there are *multiple* items matching that version number, it'll get slightly trickier - you'll probably want to group by version and then order by the group key. Basically we'd need more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I daren't edit the Skeets answer, so I'll just comment: In the first paragraph you do mean "later", don't you?

Comment: No, Skeet's right. From a string point of view, "11" is _less than_ "3".

Comment: Yea, version numbers are not decimals.  After version 3.9, you go to version 3.10 (pronounced three-dot-ten) :)

Comment: This solution will break - as Jon himself pointed out - when the version reaches "1.10".

Comment: It just didn't like the First() part of the statement, thanks for your help everyone and Skeet

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 var Max_VERSION = (from x in PList where x.PSP == LP select x.VERSION).Max();
```

Simple Example :

```
string[] versions = {"1.3","1.8","4.1","1.9", "1.4", "0.5", "1.7" };
           var max_VeRsion = (from p in versions select p).Max();
```

oops:

```
 string[] versions = {"1.3","1.8","4.2","1.9", "4.11", "0.5", "1.17" };

        var mv = (from p in versions
                 let m = versions.Max().Split(Convert.ToChar(".")).First()
                 let n = (from q in versions
                          where q.Split(Convert.ToChar(".")).First() == m
                          select Convert.ToInt32(q.Split(Convert.ToChar(".")).Last())).Max().ToString()
                 where
                     p.Split(Convert.ToChar(".")).First() == m && p.Split(Convert.ToChar(".")).Last() == n
                 select p).First();
```

Last try :)

```
        string max_version_work = (from q in
                                       (from p in versions
                                        select new
                                        {
                                            Ma = Convert.ToInt32(p.Split('.').First())
                                            ,
                                            Mi = Convert.ToInt32(p.Split('.').Last())
                                        })
                                   orderby q.Ma descending, q.Mi descending
                                   select string.Format("{0}.{1}", q.Ma, q.Mi)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Very close except it needed the ToString, thanks for your help, have an upvote!

Comment: If you add "4.2" and "4.11" to your versions, this won't yield the expected result.

Comment: I really don't mean to be rude, but... :-) if you add "10.0" to your versions, the algo won't yield the expected result.